# TeX capacity exceeded on usepackage command

Tags: errors

I'm getting the following error message and have no clue why:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000].
\@fileswithoptions #1->
                       \@ifnextchar [{\@fileswith@ptions #1}{\@fileswith@pti...
l.2 \usepackage{
                pgfplots}
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 5 strings out of 493029
 170 string characters out of 6136233
 119745 words of memory out of 5000000
 3641 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
```

The strange thing is, that this happens even with this piece of code:

```
\documentclass[article]
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The document class should be typeset with curly braces `\documentclass{article}`

Comment: Oh...guess this was a noob question. Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I also suggest you browse around the most voted questions to find "newbie" material

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in comments the error is a simple typo, using `[]` instead of `{}` but I thought I'd mention why you get the error you get (and why it is hard to give good error messages in a macro language like TeX).

The intended usage was

```
\documentclass{article}
```

with the mistaken input being

```
\documentclass[article]
```

It would have been nice to have flagged that as some kind of "wrong bracket" syntax error, but LaTeX does not know at this point that there is an error.

Like all macro arguments the class name does not *have* to be in explicit braces, the following works without error

```
\newcommand\zzz{article}
\documentclass[article]
\zzz
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Here

```
 \documentclass[article]\zzz
```

is the same as

```
 \documentclass[article]{\zzz}
```

and `\zzz` is expanded to `article` so it is the same as

```
 \documentclass[article]{article}
```

so it runs as intended, with just a warning at the end that `[article]` is an unused option:

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [article].
```

Your case is similar, except that instead of

```
   \documentclass[article]{\zzz}
```

you have (effectively)

```
   \documentclass[article]{\usepackage}
```

so TeX expands `\usepackage` hoping to find a filename to pass to `\documentclass` and dies in some horrible unintended expansion, actually it ends up in an infinite  loop until it fills up an internal macro parameter handling stack.

the best hint is the linebreak in the error message

```
l.2 \usepackage{
                pgfplots}
```

which tells you that TeX has read `\usepackage` but not its argument (because (just) `\usepackage` has been taken as the argument to `\documentclass`).